# Java 3D Texture Mapping Error

Tags: texture-mapping, java-3d, texture2d

I am new to Java 3D and I am trying to use texture mapping.  I want to add a texture to either a custom shape or a default sphere.  When I attempt to do it, the whole shape is set to the color of the bottom left pixel.  I looked at this problem [Java3d: Texture is not applied to OBJ model properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7645674/java3d-texture-is-not-applied-to-obj-model-properly)

and I tried the code given there and that did not work either.  Here is what I did.

```
Sphere sphere = new Sphere(.5f);
sphere.getAppearance().getMaterial().setShininess(10f);




try{
    File f = new File("Texture1.bmp");
    TextureLoader Texget=new TextureLoader(f.toURI().toURL(), null);

    ImageComponent2D image = Texget.getImage();
    Texture2D ourTex = new Texture2D( Texture.BASE_LEVEL,Texture.RGBA,image.getWidth(),image.getHeight() );
    ourTex.setImage(0, image);
    ourTex.setEnable(true);

    sphere.getAppearance().setTexture(ourTex);




}
catch (java.net.MalformedURLException e)
{
    System.err.println("error loading textures");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: What specifically did not work?  Are we talking compilation failures?  Are we talking logic errors?  Please be specific.

Comment: The program ran, but rather than mapping the texture to the whole shape it just set the material color to the color of the pixel in the bottom left of the image.